# Meaning of different responses to a negative imperative

Tags: meaning-in-context, imperatives

Can you answer a negative imperative such as, "Don't forget to buy some milk" with a "I will" rather than a "I won't." If so, what would it mean ?

Comment: Responding with a positive to a negative amounts to a challenge and a confrontation: "Don't do it" . . . "I will!" So if you are in concordance with the negative command, you have to reply in the negative.

Comment: *Grammatically*, you can answer that question with "I never had", "I always won't", "Susan is a fairy" or "red car". The number of grammatically correct responses is indeed *infinite*.

Comment: Maybe just say *Okay!*

Answer (score 12):

### Replying to negative imperatives in general

Yes, you can answer in both ways, but the two answers likely (though not always) mean diametrically opposite things.

Whichever way you reply, you’re basically repeating the entire sentence; the auxiliary used to create the future construction (*will*) just takes the place of the auxiliary used to create the imperative (*do*). Then the bits of the sentence that are the same (*forget to buy milk*) are left out, because we usually leave out repeated information from sentences if we can.

With some types of negative imperatives, such as this one in “don’t forget to…”, it is possible to consider the auxiliary in the reply (*will*) not just a substitution for the auxiliary *do* in the imperative, but instead for as much of the verb phrase as makes sense. In this case, that would mean *do [not] forget to buy*. This of course creates a certain amount of ambiguity, since both *will/won’t* will refer either to [not] buying milk or [not] forgetting to buy milk—exact opposites, in other words.

Which of the two possible interpretations is intended will usually be clear from the context—especially from the tone of voice and the body language the answerer uses.

This ambiguity is not possible with all negative imperatives, because often the auxiliary *do* **is** as much of the verb phrase as can be substituted and still make sense. Consider:

> — Don’t leave me!
>   — I will!

There is nothing more after *do* that can be replaced by *will* here, so “I will” **has** to be equivalent to “I will [leave you]”—it has no other option. The main verb, *leave*, can’t be included in the substitution, of course, because that would yield the ungrammatical underlying sentence “*I will you”; whereas in “Don’t forget to buy milk”, ‘expanding’ the substitution still works, because “I will [forget to buy milk]” and “I will [buy milk]” are equally grammatical and both make sense in the context. The main verb *buy* is of course akin to *leave*: “I will [milk]” is ungrammatical.

### Buying or forgetting milk

> — Don’t forget to buy milk!
>   — I won’t.

With neutral intonation and body language, you’re saying here that you *won’t* forget to buy milk; the repeated bits left out are basically “forget to buy milk”. If, on the other hand, you square your jaw and say in a defiant way, “I won’t!!!”, you could actually be stubbornly refusing to buy milk.

In this case, the first scenario will nearly always be the intended one unless there are definite context clues to indicate otherwise—the second scenario is fairly rare overall in comparison.

> — Don’t forget to buy milk!
>   — I will!

If you square your jaw and defiantly say, “I will”, you’re almost certainly saying that you *will* forget to buy milk, and (as Robusto says), you’re being a bit confrontational about it. “I don’t care if you tell me not to forget to buy milk, I’ll damn well forget to buy milk if I want to!”. That’s relatively unambiguous.

But with neutral intonation and body language, it’s a bit more ambiguous. You’re *most likely* saying that you will buy milk (just because that’s the most likely reply to an imperative like that); the repeated bits left out are then just “buy milk”.

But there is still a fair chance that you’re actually saying “I will forget to buy milk”, and a particular intonation and look can make this the more likely explanation (imagine a resigned voice and a bit of rolling your eyes at your own forgetfulness: “Yeah, you say that now, but I’ll bet once I get to the store I’ll forget the bloody milk anyway…”).

Comment: Great explanation.

Comment: Absolutely valueless explanation  :-)

Comment: @Joe How so? I thought it was fairly clear… (Or were you using _valueless_ in the archaic sense of _priceless_?)

Comment: I have submitted an answer, JBJ!  :)

Comment: BTW interestingly, you've made me think ...... *"because we usually leave out repeated information from sentences if we can."* ... BUT, does that rule apply **across speakers**?  I don't know the answer, it's just an interesting issue.  Hence, *"Here, you’re saying that you will forget to buy milk"*.  In fact, the husband is simply saying "I will."  Since this is an elision, the husband is saying "I will -something or other-".  {For completeness, husband could just be saying "I will." in a sort of abstract-verby sense - again completely normal in English.} The only reason you (reasonably)...

Comment: ...say he meant "I will -thing from the previous speaker's most recent sentence-" is this kind of rule that subjects kind of, err, continue **even across speakers**.  But like I say, I don't even know if that's a rule really. I think you'd just say "it's ambiguous."  (The norm in English.)  And then you can only say "the absolutely obvious interpretation is -sure I will purchase milk-".  I feel.

Comment: Note that (I mean in real actual life) if husband wanted to say "hell, I will forget that .. ie, I'm sure I'll forget that unfortunately" ... husband would have to spell that out .. "I will forget that." because it's just so much more likely to be the other meaning.  I think.

Comment: @Joe We do usually, yes. (See, I just left out “leave out repeated information” from your text there.) Doing so is of course a big part of the reason why almost every single utterance—not just in English, but in nearly all languages—are to some degree ambiguous. As for spelling it out, I’d say he could easily get the message across just through intonation as well.

Comment: Quite, intonation is, uh, as important in English as in Chinese.  It's fascinating that when you teach a small kid to read, you constantly and centrally give them intonation.  the CAT is FAT, etc.

Comment: So what if I reply "OK?"  My wife asks me stuff a lot like this.  For me, OK means "I will not forget to buy milk."

Comment: @michael_timofeev That would be the normal interpretation, yes. Someone like my dad would probably find it immensely amusing to reply, “Okay, I’ll do that” (referring to forgetting to buy milk, of course), but a simple _okay_ on its own generally implies agreement with an intended semantic notion, bypassing all grammatical correspondences.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I just ran this by my Chinese wife and she says (and I remember hearing this) "I would say, "OK" or "I won't."  She says by "I won't" she means "I will not forget to..."  BTW, doesn't this sentence really need a tag question?  "Don't forget to buy the milk, OK?"

Comment: @michael_timofeev Yes, those would both be the most common, default ways of phrasing agreement (that the milk should not be forgotten, that is). It only needs a tag question if you want to phrase it as a question; “don’t forget to X” is often used as a simple imperative, too.

Comment: "the second scenario is fairly rare and would require a lot of context clues to be understood."  this is wrong. it's totally commonplace. note in particular that kids are less sensitive to the notion that adults will (foolishily) interpret the elision "their" way.  the words "fairly rare" are just wrong my man.

Comment: @Joe By “a lot of context clues”, I mean for example a defiant expression and tone of voice. Are you claiming that someone replying “I won’t”, in a neutral and unmarked manner, when told not to forget to buy milk will totally commonplacely be refusing to buy milk? I for one have never come across that.

Comment: Right, that's exactly what I'm saying. It's totally normal that someone will interpret the whole clause: **Don't forget to buy some milk** as an **idiomatic phrase meaning** "please buy milk" .. let us say as a **fixed indivisiable unit**. This is totally and completely commonplace. Moreover, 30% of people are so stupid they would not even realise what this conversation is about as they wouldn't *even get* the double-negative. For example, it would be utterly normal to reply simply **yes** (meaning, of course, "yes I'll get milk", not continuing the blah blah implied subject inside the idiom).

Comment: "I for one have never come across that" as is often the case on this site you and your friends are too intelligent, it's why you have me  * smiley! *

Comment: An incredibly simple example is that "not bad" now means "good" as a **fixed indivisible unit**.  If you respond to "not bad" in some way that tries to **pick apart the double-negative**, it would be completely confusing.

Comment: @Joe I have both used and heard “Don’t forget to X” imperatives hundreds or thousands of times, and by far the most common replies I’ve heard are variations of “I won’t” and “Okay/all right”, said in a neutral voice. I have never once heard anyone understand those replies to mean that the replier was refusing to buy milk. Never. That’s nothing to do with intelligence (it works just fine with kids, too).

Comment: "the two answers likely (though not always) mean diametrically opposite things" only if you are assuming that the subject implied in the elision is the one from the other speaker's previous sentence

Answer (score 0):

It is utterly normal in English to shorten phrases or words, leave out words, omit phrases. English is elision madness.

> "Don't forget the milk!"
>
> "Sure, I will!"

Here the husband is saying

> "Sure, I will buy some milk!"

(1) This makes, on the face of it, an ambiguity.  ("It could literally mean *'I will forget!'*  See, an ambiguity!")

(2) So what?

All you can really say here is

(1) It is absolutely, totally, completely normal to have **ambiguity in English**.

(2) You've pointed out a "fun" example of an ambiguity, caused by elision.  Note that elision is so common in English that .... well it's as common as "verbs" you know?  (It's utterly commonplace to elide verbs!)

One way to look at this QA is, all you've really done is pointed out a particular sort of "humorous ambiguity" in English -- you see what I mean?

(Note that, it's incredibly easy to **state WHOLE CATEGORIES OF** humorous ambiguity in English.)

Of course, obviously, Janus above has flawlessly explained the "literal" meaning of what you discuss. But you hardly don't never hear anything literal in spoken English.

Comment: In this context, you can (colloquially) use “I will” to mean the same as “I won’t”, true—that’s because you can stretch the substitution “do [not]” → “will” to be instead “do [not] forget to” → “will”. That’s not the case for negative imperatives in general, though: if someone tells you, “Don’t leave me!” and you reply, “I will!”, it’ll take some _very_ liberal interpretation to make that mean, “Okay, I’ll stay here with you”.

Comment: You know that's an interesting example (leave me etc.) but, funnily enough I think it's quite normal that in that example the husband makes that "mistake" and you both know what he meant!  It's quite normal to trip over double-negatives (or whatever the hell they are) in English, don't you think?  It's a little like (a) "I love you" (b) "Me too.." everyone knows b's statement means b loves a, but it's highly non-literal (just as in your example).

Comment: Eg, I'm sure I've literally said to my girlfriend, (she) "Don't leave me to deal with the damn recycling bags!" (me) "OK I will for sure! Heh I mean I will take them out, not that I'll leave you with them!" What you describe as very liberal interpretation, I would say more "is a bit of a common mixup in English"  You know?